# Include html file in body email with email-ext plugin in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext

I need include email content from html file using email-ext plugin in jenkins pipeline (my jenkins is 2.24 version), i try this

```
emailext (
  subject: "some subject",
  body: "${FILE,path="enteryPath/template.html"}",
  to: "email@example.com"
)
```

but dont work for me :( any suggestions or solution?? , thanks advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to attach files to Jenkins Pipeline notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422526/how-to-attach-files-to-jenkins-pipeline-notification)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `attachmentsPattern` parameter.

```
emailext (
  subject: "some subject",
  body: "${FILE,path="enteryPath/template.html"}",
  to: "email@example.com"
  attachmentsPattern: 'enteryPath/template.html'
)
```

Comment: Where to place in my html file ?

Comment: @vijay you can place it anywhere where Jenkins has read permissions.

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko, lets say template.html has an <img> tag on it? 
<img src="F:\Jenkins\workspace\ws\footer.JPG"> how are we going to define it? using the image snippet here doesnt work for me. any thoughts?

Comment: @PANDAMAN I believe you should use some sort of hosting for the image instead of store it on Jenkins machine. But this is really out of scope for this question. Please create another one or search existing.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you store the body in the workspace? And then just run:

```
emailext (
  subject: "some subject",
  body: readFileFromWS("enteryPath/template.html"),
  to: "email@example.com"
)
```

But this would mean the body is static from job-creation and forward, guess you want it to be read when the mail should be sent?

Answer (score 0):

```
    stage ('email'){
    steps{
      script{
             echo "hello"
             emailext (subject: "some subject", body: '${FILE,path="template.html"}',to: "xyz@gmail.com")  

            }
        }       
  }
```

Install the *email-ext* plugin for Jenkins and you can have the above code to send emails as part of the stage and *path* here would be relative to Jenkins workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of ***readFile***()

```
emailext (
            mimeType: 'text/html',
            to: "sample@email.com",
            attachLog: true,
            subject: 'Subject Line',
            body: readFile("path/to/html/file")
        )
```

***readFile*** will read it as stream of strings and hands it over to emailext plugin, hence if you might have used any special variables such as

> ${BUILD_NUMBER}

> ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX}

will get compiled correctly and replaced with interpreted values.