# How to attach files to Jenkins Pipeline notification

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext

I am trying in a pipeline to attach files to my notification mails.

How can I do that? An example would be nice.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

email-ext uses [Ant File Syntax](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html)

As for example usage:

```
emailext attachmentsPattern: '**/report.html', body: 'Find attachments', subject: 'test', to: 'test@me.org'
```

Comment: attachementPattern does not accept all file path ?? for example ${workspace}/file.xml

Comment: works as expected. another thing that is important in this context, is another boolean key/value 'attachLog: true' . not to be confused (as i did...) - the boolean is only for sending the build log of jenkins itself, rather than 'attachmentsPattern' which allow to customize based on Ant patterns

Comment: def file_name = "file.txt" and calling `attachmentsPattern: "${file_name}"`. its unable to call that file. please suggest

Comment: if there are two files then?

Comment: Hi @Khan, would you be able to write a pattern that matches both of them?

Comment: For example the all files in a folder reports, so can I do like `**/reports/*`

Comment: The first start should be doubled unless you can provide a full path (then it matches all report directories in your working directory tree). Then you need a star at the end to pick all the files in the matched directories.

EDIT: yeah, just like you edited.

Comment: Also you can add specific more than one file:
attachmentsPattern: 'report.html, test.html,....'

Comment: I am getting ERROR: Error accessing files to attach: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw '/tmp/output.text' ...... I want to attach file /tmp/output.text

Comment: @AshishKarpe this pattern is relative to your workspace, you would need to do ../ as many times to get to the /, and then have the rest of it, for example ../../../../tmp/output.text

Comment: @hakamairi I tried to cp /tmp/output.text $WORKSPACE/ but my workspace is getting cleaned so getting error