# How to send attachments through jenkins pipeline using mail

Tags: email, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured my jenkins pipeline to send mail like this

```
post { 
success {
    mail bcc: '', body: 'this is the body', cc: '', from: '', replyTo: '', subject: 'This is a test', to: 'xyz@gmail.com' 
    }   
}
```

Now, I would like to send an attachment along with this, but, could not able to find out any option for that. Does anyone knows how to send attachment with the above syntax. I will be thankful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to attach files to Jenkins Pipeline notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422526/how-to-attach-files-to-jenkins-pipeline-notification)

Comment: may be..but i want answer specific for `mail` not for `emailext` plugin

Comment: Hello, is there an answer for this ? I can't use the plugin 'emailext', i'm not the sysadmin of the jenkins platform